# vue-resource: How is success of a $http request determined?

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

In vue-resource, while making a call such as:

```
 this.$http.post('/someUrl', formData).then(response => {
    // success callback
  }, response => {
    // error callback
  });
```

how is whether the success or failure callback will be executed chosen? Is it determined by some property of the response object?

Comment: Yes, it is. the returned http code, here a [List of HTTP codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) from wiki 200 is success and many other are different status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise will reject if the response status is not in the 200's, in which case `response.ok` will be false.